# change web.config appsettings based on globalization setting

Tags: .net, globalization, web-config

I am using common code for 2 different international sites but with different web.config settings.

I'd like to keep both sets of the appsettings in the same web.config file and just change the globalization settings for each installation.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Find tag  in web.config
and then add the next line the culture you like
for example

```
.....
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="ro-Ro" uiCulture="ro-Ro" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
.....
```

The other way but less beautifull is to set the culture for request thread. This is can be done in global.asax file specifing Begin_Request method and .